# Reading QR Codes from image file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I want to read Qr codes from picture files in flutter without using the firebase ML kit.

So far I was able to create the image picker but don't know what to do next.

Dependency: `image_picker: ^0.8.4+1`

scan.dart:

```
File? _image;
Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Theme.of(context).buttonColor),
            onPressed: () async => pickImage(),
            icon: Icon(Icons.image),
            label: Text("Choose an Image from gallery"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

Future<void> pickImage() async {
    await Permission.storage.request();
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;

    if (status.isGranted) {
      final pickedFile =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(
          () {
            this._image = File(pickedFile.path);
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this package. You can pass the file and read the qr as expected.

https://pub.dev/packages/scan

Comment: I have already tried using the package but the package does not have null safety and gives an error when I run it.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_qr_scan/example
This one is also good. It's null safe too

Comment: the popularity of the package is not so good

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: the scan package worked please remove the previous answer so I can mark it as an answer

Comment: Edited my answer. Glad it worked :)

Comment: When i use scan package its giving me this error ?
dequeuebuffer: bufferqueue has been abandoned